# Remove field from MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB to store my data. I got a collection whichs documents have this look:

```
{
  "_id": UUID("61d2a9c4-0d8a-4106-ab50-8d4ada96bfdf"),
  "some": "field",
  "data": {
    "1d19bca7-7edb-4085-a2c3-fa92c6faf3bd": {
      "a": "nested object"
    },
    "7f812369-c4ff-4e90-9f2c-27904bb03e8d": {
      "a": "nother nested object"
    }
  }
}
```

I would now like to remove `data.7f812369-c4ff-4e90-9f2c-27904bb03e8d`. I tried it with `$unset` but you can just set the field to `null` but not remove it. Another approach I did was using `$pull` but I thinks it's only assumed to be used for arrays. So how could I remove the `data.7f812369-c4ff-4e90-9f2c-27904bb03e8d` field?

Any help appreciated

---

EDIT:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').update({
  "_id": UUID("61d2a9c4-0d8a-4106-ab50-8d4ada96bfdf")
}, {
  $unset: {
    "data.1d19bca7-7edb-4085-a2c3-fa92c6faf3bd": null
  }
});
```

actually works. Can't remember what I did wrong the other when. Thanks alot to everybody helping.

Comment: the `$unset` did remove the key from collection. At least in my server.

Comment: `$unset` is how you do this. Can you update your question to show what you're trying with `$unset`? The `null` setting only occurs within array fields, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: `$unset` will only result to `null` if you are trying to unset any array index. `$unset` is the right way to do this , since you are not working with arrays,